# Visual Basic Threading.Thread not working as i want, whats wrong in my code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

My code is below

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For i = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
        Dim MessageThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Checkpath)
        MessageThread.Start(i)
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub Checkpath(ByVal i As Integer)
    Dim url As String
    Try
        url = RichTextBox1.Lines(i).ToString
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim resUri As String
        response = req.GetResponse
        resUri = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
        RichTextBox2.AppendText(resUri & vbNewLine)
    Catch ex As Exception
        unexpected += 1
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Label6.Text = "Unexpected: " & unexpected
    End Try
End Sub
```

When ever i do this i get error that

> Richtextbox i is array outside of bound

but if i use msgbox(i) before the code,

```
Public Sub Checkpath(ByVal i As Integer)
    MsgBox(i)
    Dim url As String
    Try
        url = RichTextBox1.Lines(i).ToString
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim resUri As String
        response = req.GetResponse
        resUri = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
        RichTextBox2.AppendText(resUri & vbNewLine)
    Catch ex As Exception
        unexpected += 1
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Label6.Text = "Unexpected: " & unexpected
    End Try
End Sub
```

works fine or if i do like this

```
    Public Sub Checkpath(ByVal i As Integer)

    Dim url As String
    Try
        MsgBox(i)
        url = RichTextBox1.Lines(i).ToString
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim resUri As String
        response = req.GetResponse
        resUri = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
        RichTextBox2.AppendText(resUri & vbNewLine)
    Catch ex As Exception
        unexpected += 1
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Label6.Text = "Unexpected: " & unexpected
    End Try
End Sub
```

it works fine but i don't want to display the msgbox

any solution without the msgbox thing?

Comment: You can't safely access controls on any thread other than the UI thread. Nothing else is likely to work after you do that. What you could do is get the lines into an array first and then pass the line, rather than the index of the line, to the thread. You still can't update the UI at the end of the thread that way though. You need to do much more reading on the subject and try again.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a thread here?  If the issue is that you don't want to block the UI while you wait for the response from the remote website, this is the canonical example for using `Await` instead of explicitly coding a thread (especially since something that is I/O bound doesn't actually need another thread to be asynchronous).

Comment: If the point is to parallelize, then there should be example code in the Task-based Parallelism help topics on MSDN on how to set this example up as a string of `Task` objects and then await them all.